# SQL Server vs. Oracle differences guide - Variables

Tags: sql-server, oracle

Lets say I want to take the current time, subtract 1 hour from it and query a table with that time.

In SQL Server, I would do the following:

```
    DECLARE @a datetime = DATEADD(hour, -1, GETDATE())
    --I can then return for troubleshooting via
    SELECT @a
    --And use in a select query via
    SELECT * FROM Table t WHERE(t.datetime >= @a)
```

In Oracle I can do the following:

```
    --Subtract 1 hour from now
    SELECT systimestamp(3) - interval '1' hour FROM dual;

    --But when I try to use the following it doesn't work
    DECLARE a timestamp := (SELECT systimestamp(3) - interval '1' hour FROM dual);
    BEGIN
      SELECT :a FROM dual;
    END;

    --Also, I've tried this
    variable a timestamp  := (SELECT systimestamp(3) - interval '1' hour FROM dual);
    SELECT :a from dual;

    --And, this...
    DECLARE a timestamp;
    BEGIN
      SELECT (systimestamp(3) - interval '1' hour) INTO a FROM dual
      SELECT :a FROM dual;
    END;

    --And, lastly this...
    def a timestamp := (SELECT systimestamp(3) - interval '1' hour FROM dual);
    SELECT :a FROM dual;
    SELECT &a FROM dual;

    --My goal
    var a timestamp := (SELECT systimestamp(3) - interval '1' hour FROM dual);
    SELECT * FROM table t WHERE(t.datetime >= &a);
    --Also have the ability to test the calculated variable for troubleshooting via
    SELECT &a FROM dual;
```

The example above isn't necessarily what I want to calculate, but just an example.

I don't wish to manually type the input, I want to calculate a variable to be used inside the query.  Can Oracle not do this?

Comment: I think you don't want a "variable". Just use the expression: `systimestamp(3) - interval '1' hour`

Comment: I'd like the ability to have all changeable values at the top of the query, so a user can change them to whatever.  e.g. 24 hours instead of 1.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SELECT..INTO` in this case:

```
DECLARE
  a timestamp;
BEGIN
  SELECT systimestamp(3) - interval '1' hour
    INTO a
    FROM dual;
END;
```

or you can just assign to the variable:

```
DECLARE
  a timestamp;
BEGIN
  a := systimestamp(3) - interval '1' hour;
END;
```

Best of luck.

Comment: The first example only returns "anonymous block completed", when I try to output the variable via

Comment: "select a from dual;" it fails.  For the second, it fails on the assignment, but if I convert the datatype to a  number it works.  However, when outputting the variable from dual it fails like the first example.  Also, how can I create a variable to control the number of hours to subtract for the user?

Comment: I'm sorry to have to break this to you, but in order to output anything from inside a PL/SQL block you're going to have to use either DBMS_OUTPUT or UTL_FILE. There is no other way. Executing `SELECT a FROM DUAL` will do nothing but throw an error. I strongly suggest using an IDE which makes retrieving text from DBMS_OUTPUT easy, such as Oracle's SQL Developer (free), or Allround Automation's similarly-named PL/SQL Developer (costs money).